# Material UI - The `component` prop provided to ButtonBase is invalid. Please make sure the children prop is rendered in this custom component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Apologies for the basic question in advance, I'm not a strong frontend developer, and I have scoured the internet. I keep getting this error when I inspect my frontend app in chrome.

> (3) Material-UI: The `component` prop provided to ButtonBase is
> invalid. Please make sure the children prop is rendered in this custom
> component.

Why are the social button tabs throwing this error?

Here is the code...

```
import React, {forwardRef} from 'react';
import '../../styles/header.css';
import {Link, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Paper, Tabs, Tab} from '@material-ui/core';
import {Email, GitHub, LinkedIn} from '@material-ui/icons';


const Header: React.FC = () => {
    const location = useLocation();

    const renderSocialButton = (link: string, children: JSX.Element): JSX.Element => (
        <a href={link}> 
            {children}
        </a>
    );

    return (
        <Paper square>
            <Tabs
                value={location.pathname}
                indicatorColor='primary'
                textColor='primary'
                aria-label='menu tabs'
                centered
            >   
                <Tab 
                    label='Home'
                    className={'tab_nav'}
                    component={Link}
                    to={'/'}
                    value={'/'} 
                />
                <Tab 
                    label='About'
                    className={'tab_nav'}
                    component={Link}
                    to={'/about'}
                    value={'/about'} 
                />
                <Tab 
                    label=''
                    className={'space_nav'}
                    disabled
                />
                <Tab 
                    component={ forwardRef(() => 
                        renderSocialButton('https://example.com', <Email className={'social_icon'} />)
                    )}
                />
                <Tab 
                    component={ forwardRef(() => 
                        renderSocialButton('https://example.com', <GitHub className={'social_icon'} />)
                    )}
                />
                <Tab 
                    component={ forwardRef(() => 
                        renderSocialButton('https://example.com', <LinkedIn className={'social_icon'} />)
                    )}
                />
            </Tabs>
        </Paper>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you're having problems because of the way that you're passing in a function inside of your `component` prop.

The Material UI [docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/) suggest that you should "avoid inline functions and pass a static component to the component prop instead."

Ex. (from the docs):

```js
const CustomLink = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      React.forwardRef((linkProps, ref) => (
        <Link ref={ref} to={to} {...linkProps} />
      )),
    [to],
  );
```

Then you could pass that inside of your `component` prop, rather than the function.